# How can I orchestrate multiple business tasks?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I have a WebApi backend with a Blazor WASM frontend. The application is split up into 3 main parts. Core, Infrastructure and Presentation. Basic onion architecture structure.

**Core.Domain** Domain objects/entities
**Core.Application** Application releveant interfaces and CQRS commands and handlers
**Infrastructure.xxx** Projects which implement the interfaces defined in Core.Application. Like Infrastructure.Persistence for database access
**Presentation.Backend** The WebApi
**Presentation.Frontend** Blazor WASM SPA

So I have an HTTP endpoint which accepts a command. It will be sent to a handler which will process the command and returns some kind of result.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterCommand command)
{
    var result = Mediator.Send(command);

    if(result.Success)
    {
        return Ok(..);
    }

    return BadRequest(..);
}
```

But what happens when I want to send a confirmation email after the user was registered successfully? Which part is responsible for triggering the mail?
Currently my command handler takes care of both tasks. But that feels wrong. A command handler should only take care of one task.

One approach would be some kind of eventaggregator which seems to be a good way in this case. *Just* fire an event `UserCreated` and some handle will take care of it. I mean I could just publish a new command which would be the same basically.

But what when I want to wait for the result of my second task? Lets take a shop order. The example might not be very accurate I was just trying to give you some example of what I want to avoid

```
Handler(ShopOrderCommand command)
{
    if(Validate(command) == ValidationResult.Suspicious)
    {
        MarkAsSuspicious();
        return;
    }

    foreach(var item in command.ShoppingCart)
    {
        RemoveItemFromShopInventory(item);
    }

    if(command.IsGuestOrder) 
    {
        RegisterTemporaryUser(..);
    }

    var id = CreateOrder(..);
    CreateTransportLabel(id);
    AssignPacker(id, command.Priority);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mentioned approaches here, so I'll give you a quick rundown of possible approaches.

---

For **fire and forget** actions, such as sending an email notification, Mediatr (the library) uses a [notification publish](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/237) approach. It's done just like firing a request, and I suspect the difference between a request (with no return value) and a notification is semantical more than it is technical - except that notifications *cannot* send a return value, whereas requests *could* send one if they wanted to.

I notice that your code isn't using the Mediatr library, but it's a good source of inspiration on how to approach these kinds of things. My advice is to stick with what's tried and true, unless you have concrete reasons to do it differently.

You already touched on this idea:

> One approach would be some kind of eventaggregator which seems to be a good way in this case. Just fire an event `UserCreated` and some handle will take care of it. I mean I could just publish a new command which would be the same basically.

And you're right, it's not that different from firing a mediator command. I would argue that there is a difference, but it's semantical, not technical.

- `CreateUser` is a command. It contains the logic that creates a user.
- `UserCreated` is a notification/event. It contains **subsequent logic** that should happen after a user has been created.

So you might use a `SendEmail` command, or a `UserCreated` event. Either could contain the logic for sending out an email that the user was created.

**You might want to use both**. In cases when you send many kinds of emails, `SendEmail` is too vague, and you'd end up with all sorts of `SendFooEmail`, `SendBarEmail`, ... commands. That's not preferable.
Similarly, if you take many separate actions after a user was created, you're going to end up with multiple `UserCreated` event handlers, and you'd similarly need to name them `UserCreatedFooHandler`, `UserCreatedBarHandler`, ... and that's not preferable either.

By using both, you avoid having to create these highly specific names. Instead, you can simply have a single `UserCreated` event handler which in turn fires a  `SendEmail` command. Any user-creation-specific work, such as generating the content of the mail body and subject line, choosing the right recipient, ... can be done in the event handlers, whereas `SendEmail` takes in more generalized input (so its interface is not specific to the kind of email you're sending), so it can be reused across all instances where you want to send an email.

This helps you keep the names of your event handlers and commands simple, and the event handler logic becomes easier to read because it doesn't contain the nitty gritty implementation details, instead only orchestrating the subsequent commands that need to fire after the current event was triggered.

---

If you want to **wait for completion**, there are two ways of doing this. Either you chain commands, or you abstract your lower level logic into services.

Using the Mediatr example again, chaining commands is fairly easy since your command handler can simply request an `IMediator` injected dependency, and then your command handler can publish a new command on that object.
It is, in essence, the same as publishing a notification (mentioned before), but in this case you are actually able to receive a return value and change your original command's behavior based on it.

You could instead abstract your lower level logic into services. This is what I tend to do in most cases. This is simply a matter of making a domain service (or other appropriate layer, e.g. a datalayer repository) which handles part of the nitty gritty implementation details of the subtasks in your command. Your command then sort of becomes the orchestrator of its own responsibilities.

It also bears mentioning that using services for subtasks isn't that uncommon, and you've probably already been doing it, e.g. when you query a repository to get the data that your command needs to work with. What I'm mentioning here is the exact same thing, except that the service in question could live in the domain/application layer instead of the data layer. Same idea, different layer.

As far as I'm aware, the preference of chaining commands or creating services for subtasks is mostly a subjective choice. It depends on if you want to keep the amount of commands down, if you want to specifically use commands instead of services, ... these are all relatively personal (to the codebase) considerations that I can't provide a universal answer to.